# Alienware R3 touchpad light in linux

Tags: hardware, touchpad, backlight

I got a new Gentoo linux install running great on my new Alienware 13" R3 laptop.

The keyboard lights light up great, but not the touch pad...which does light up in Windows.

Does anyone how to make the touch pad light up in linux?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using some kind of usb library like https://github.com/trackmastersteve/alienfx to talk to your keyboard lights.

I tweaked that library and made my own controller to get it working for my machine (you can find it [here](https://github.com/Yashasvi-Sriram/alieneffects-13r3https://github.com/Yashasvi-Sriram/alieneffects-13r3)), but the trackpad backlight was not switching on.

Changing **Trackpad Backlight** (or some similar setting) from **Auto** to **On** in BIOS settings worked and I was even able to control the color.

In case I need to save power, I just set its color to black.